# patsubst and compiling source files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

As I understand the below lines in my makefile should compile all source files in current directory

```
SRC=Connection.cpp Request.cpp SessionHandler.cpp
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SRC))

$(OBJS) : | obj
obj:
        @mkdir -p $@
obj/%.o : %.cpp
        g++ -std=c++11 -c $< -o $@
```

But only first file in $(SRC) gets compiled and place object in ./obj

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c Connection.cpp -o obj/Connection.o
```

What I am missing here ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be **one** default goal in a makefile.

Controlling the default goal is discussed in the GNU Make Manual in the [Arguments to Specify the Goals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) section.

The crucial bit of which, for this question, is:

> By default, the goal is the first target in the makefile (not counting targets that start with a period).

In your case the default target is therefore `obj/Connection.o` because this bit of your makefile

```
$(OBJS) : | obj
```

expands to

```
obj/Connection.o obj/Request.o obj/SessionHandler.o: | obj
```

which is equivalent to

```
obj/Connection.o: | obj
obj/Request.o: | obj
obj/SessionHandler.o: | obj
```

To get all your object files built by default you want to replace

```
$(OBJS) : | obj
```

with

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)
```